# running tinylog inside glassfish

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, tinylog

I'm trying to run tinylog inside glassfish 3.1.2.2. First I copied tinylog.jar into `/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`. Second I created `tinylog.properties` inside `domain1/config`. `tinylog.properties` is like this:

```
tinylog.format={date}-[{class}:{method}:{line}]-{level}-{message}
tinylog.writer=rollingfile
tinylog.writer.filename=log.txt
tinylog.writer.backups=5
tinylog.writer.label=count
tinylog.writer.policies=size: 10KB
```

My application is a simple web service like this:

```
@WebService
public class Calculator {
    @WebMethod
    public int sum(int a, int b) {
        Logger.info("new request. a = {0}, b = {1}", a, b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Now when I ran web service it works and returns results. But logs are inside `logs/server.log` like this:

```
[#|2012-09-08T14:15:03.801+0430|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=175;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|2012-09-08 14:15:03 [http-thread-pool-8080(1)] com.argengco.tiny.Calculator.sum()
INFO: new request. a = 43, b = 7
|#]
```

since tinylog writes logs to stdout by default and  glassfish redirects stdout to `javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging` logger, it seems tinylog did  not find `tinylog.properties`. I don't see any permission error in `server.log` which tells it can not open `tinylog.properties`. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If /glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1 is the root of your source build tree (i.e. it contains com/blah/blah) then you need to either:

1) Put the tinylog.properties file in that directory

or

2) Call `PropertiesLoader.loadFromFile("config/tinylog.properties");`

I came across your question after trying to find the answer myself. After rebuilding the source code with some debug messaging (minor irony!) I worked out the answer.

In my case I had a src/com/blah/blah directory structure. In this case the tinylog.properties file needs to go in the src/ directory.